# jQuery add and remove class of parent to create an accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to make the clickElementGeneralDivProducts class a nowCollapse or Now collapsed class at the click of the button.
Did you already do something like this?
Thanks in advance

this is my html:

```
    <div class="row viewElementGeneraleDivProdotti nowcollapse">
          <button class="accordionType">
              <div class="openclose accordion-header viewNomeProdottoSingolo nowcollapse">Master Frit</div>
            <div class="viewIconRightPlus">
              <div class="toggle-plus">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
             </div>
          </button>
          <div class="openclose accordion-content panel-collapse nowcollapse">
            <div class="viewImageAndDescription">
              <div class="viewImmagineProdottoSingolo"><img src="http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/59INBIIVpr1GukNtJs-wpcf_210x300.jpg" title="59INBIIVpr1GukNtJs" class="attachment-medium"></div>
              <div class="viewDescrizioneProdotto"><p>Olio di palma frazionato, ideale per fritture e con punto di fumo ˃ 220°</p>
</div></div></div></div>
```

this is my jquery:

```
jQuery('.accordionType').on('click', function() {
 if (jQuery('.viewElementGeneraleDivProdotti').hasClass(".nowcollapse")) {
   $('.viewElementGeneraleDivProdotti').removeClass(".nowcollapse");
$('.viewElementGeneraleDivProdotti').addClass(".nowcollapsed");
  }
  else
  {
   $('.viewElementGeneraleDivProdotti').removeClass(".nowcollapse");
$('.viewElementGeneraleDivProdotti').addClass(".nowcollapsed");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.` from the className when checking, removing and adding class to the element. `.` is used only when you are selecting the element by its class name.

```
$('.accordionType').on('click', function() {
    const parent = $(this).parents('.viewElementGeneraleDivProdotti');
    if(parent.hasClass('nowcollapse')) {
        parent.removeClass('nowcollapse').addClass('nowcollapsed')
    } else {
        parent.removeClass('nowcollapsed').addClass('nowcollapse')
    }
});
```

```js
$('.accordionType').on('click', function() {
        const parent = $(this).parents('.viewElementGeneraleDivProdotti');
        if(parent.hasClass('nowcollapse')) {
            parent.removeClass('nowcollapse').addClass('nowcollapsed')
        } else {
            parent.removeClass('nowcollapsed').addClass('nowcollapse')
        }
    });
```

```css
.nowcollapse .content {display: none;}
.nowcollapsed .content {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row viewElementGeneraleDivProdotti nowcollapse">
          <button class="accordionType">Toggle
          </button>
          <div class="content">Content here</div>
</div>
```